# How to populate a html 5 date input

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a modal that opens with form data to be edited. Everything populates correctly except the date input. When I put a date in there it saves and updates fine so is it a format issue? The input field is showing mm/dd/yy when the modal opens.
[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/uBTHqY1zhtdZ1LrnI8NT?p=preview)

```
<label style="margin-left:296px">Date:</label>
                                            <input style="width:150px" ng-model="currentItem.ChangeOrderDate" type="date" />
```

Comment: Check your console...errors...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should convert the string to date object before populating.

```
$scope.currentItem = {ChangeOrderDate  : new Date('2014-08-27T07:41:43.803')};
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/yXsFEP?p=preview)**

Comment: How would that work with this modal service? http://plnkr.co/edit/iAKyxnsRkuc476sccXv1?p=preview

Comment: @user3919120 you are using older version of angular, for that just use the date format "YYYY-MM-DD" `'2014-08-27'`  http://plnkr.co/edit/z6trUO?p=preview